# How to check values of different rows of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have below sample input table. In real it has lots of records.

Input:

| ID | Classification |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 123 | 4 |
| 657 | 1 |
| 657 | 3 |
| 657 | 4 |

For a 'ID', I want it's records should have 'Classification' column contains all the values 1, 2, 3 and 4. If any of these values are not present then that ID's records should be considered as an exception. The output should be as below.

| ID | Classification | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 0 |
| 123 | 2 | 0 |
| 123 | 3 | 0 |
| 123 | 4 | 0 |
| 657 | 1 | 1 |
| 657 | 3 | 1 |
| 657 | 4 | 1 |

Can someone please help me with how can this can be achieved in sql server.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a correlated subquery (there plenty of examples out there on how to check the existing all a range of values), or (windowed) conditional aggregates? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here, which is more performant is up to you to test, not me (especially when I don't know what indexes you have). One uses conditional aggregation, to check that all the values are there, and the other uses a subquery and counts the `DISTINCT` values (as I don't know if there could be duplicate classifications):

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(123,1),
            (123,2),
            (123,3),
            (123,4),
            (657,1),
            (657,3),
            (657,4))V(ID,Classification);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_YourIndex ON dbo.YourTable (ID,Classification);
GO

SELECT ID,
       Classification,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE YT.Classification WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) > 0
             AND COUNT(CASE YT.Classification WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) > 0
             AND COUNT(CASE YT.Classification WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) > 0 
             AND COUNT(CASE YT.Classification WHEN 4 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS Flag
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
GO

SELECT ID,
       Classification,
       CASE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sq.Classification)
             FROM dbo.YourTable sq
             WHERE sq.ID = YT.ID
               AND sq.Classification IN (1,2,3,4)) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS Flag
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```